# angular-scroll conflict with jQuery 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to use [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll). I'm using the scrollTo function within my template:

```
<li class="tab col s2"><a class="menupoints" du-smooth-scroll="#section-3" du-scrollspy>Kontakt</a></li>
```

Problem is, that i also have to use jQuery 2.1.1 and this is somehow conflicting. I always get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I know that my implementation is correct, because when i remove jQuery 2.1.1 everything works fine. So is there ways to resolve this conflict?

Comment: what browser are you testing in? is it one that is supported by jQuery 2.1.1?

Comment: Good question :) Chrome: Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

Comment: are you loading jQuery before angular ?

Comment: Yes ;) In grunt (bower_concat) i made a dependency for that